# Firebase extension failing with error code 429

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I am trying to install the firebase stripe payments extension for my project but it is failing with the below error

`; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/createCustomer: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"429","ResourceErrorMessage":"Build failed: Too many concurrent builds, please stagger your deployments."}; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-firestore-stripe-payments/resources/createCheckoutSession: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"429","ResourceErrorMessage":"Build failed: Too many concurrent builds, please stagger your deployments."}`

I tried manual installation and via console but the error persist